# Viewing Beaten Games on Steam

Tags: steam

In your personal Steam profile you can see your average game completion percentage (which, for me, sits at a pathetic 33%).  However, I can't seem to find a way to see which of these games Steam considers actually completed.  Simply looking at a game's achievements does not seem enough for me: for instance, the game Splice has a main game and an epilogue, but is the game completed when the main section is, or only when you've finished the epilogue?

Even if these details were obvious from looking at a game's achievements, going through every game you own and checking these achievements requires a ridiculous amount of time if your Steam account is like many peoples'.  If Steam already feels it knows what games you've completed I was hoping they might also have a list of said games.  So the question is, is there a way to see a list of all games that Steam believes you have completed (but not necessarily gotten 100% achievements on)?

**EDIT:** See comment on accepted answer.

Comment: Are you asking how you can see a list of your completed games, or are you just wanting to know how you can see at all if a game is considered beaten?

Comment: You can use [this tool](http://wastedonsteam.com/usd) and sort the list "Library of games" by Achievements.  Note that it may take a while to analyze your Steam account.

Comment: I was hoping to see a list of completed games.  Clearly Steam is calculating that somehow with its Game Completion Rate but I am sure it is more complicated.  For instance, in a game like Splice (http://store.steampowered.com/app/209790/), is it completed when I've finished the main game or only after I've finished the Epilogue?  Do some multiplayer games (TF2) even have a possible completion, and if not, are they counted in this rate or not?  I suppose there is lots I could ask, but this is just the basic thing I was hoping to find out.  (Question updated to reflect this)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steam does not provide an exclusive list of games you have *completed*, but you can go through your library of games one by one and check if you have 100% of the achievements for that game - if you do, Steam considers you to have *beaten* the game.

Comment: Oh, thanks!  I actually discovered I was misunderstanding what "Game Completion Rate" meant.  I thought it meant I had completed 33% of games (IE, seen them through to some point of conclusion).  What it actually means is that I have earned 33% of all achievements available among games I've played.  That makes this make a lot more sense.